# cancel a PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a `PendingIntent` which is used in an `AlarmManager`  The `PendingIntent`s have unique ids which I keep track of.  Because of this, I should be able to cancel the `PendingIntent` by passing the unique id when I try to cancel it.  I am trying to cancel it in a different `Fragment` from the one I created it in, if that makes any difference.

But I have not been able to cancel it even after looking at many past questions.

I have looked at eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350149/2442638 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257277/2442638 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682008/2442638

This is how I create the `PendingIntent` and set it with the `AlarmManager`:

```
// remCounter is unique for each PendingIntent

Intent remIntent = new Intent();
                remIntent.setAction("com.example.test.remBroadcast");
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("content_title", (String) s_content_title);
                extras.putString("content_text", (String) s_content_text);
                extras.putBoolean("bOngoing", boolean_ongoing);
                extras.putInt("remCounter", remCounter); // This is how I keep track of the unique id. I have proved this to work.
                remIntent.putExtras(extras);


                PendingIntent remPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        getActivity(), remCounter, remIntent, 

                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                getActivity(); // (Do I need this?)
                AlarmManager remAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                remAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        setForCal,
                        remPendingIntent);
```

This is how I'm trying to cancel a PendingIntent:

```
// cancelCounter is the value of the unique id of the PendingIntent I want to cancel

    Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),
                cancelCounter, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        pi.cancel();
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.cancel(pi);
```

Comment: `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` will run only once and then cancel itself. refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Thanks, but I would like to stop it from running, even if it is only going to run once.

Comment: `Intent remIntent = new Intent()` `remIntent.setAction("com.example.test.remBroadcast");` then
`PendingIntent remPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        getActivity(), remCounter, remIntent, 

                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`
`am.cancel(remPendingIntent)`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Thanks! I needed to use the same flag